# python zip() function adding a new sequence

Tags: python

As you know zip() takes sequences as parameters and returns a list of tuples of elements mapped between those sequences. My question is : what if i have an undefined number of sequences?

lets say i have:

```
index=range(0,5)
field=['name','surname','age','gender','location']
data1=['john','nash','88','m','konya']
data2=['david','davidoff','100','m','istanbul']
```

if i use zip like below:

```
zip(index,field,data1,data2)
```

it works perfect, however my data is not limited to data1 and data2. I may have up to 10 records for each individual. I tried to append datai`s to another data[] array, however zip did not consider this as seperate sequences.

```
data=[]
data.append(data1)
data.append(data2)
zip(index,field,data)
```

gives no useful data as expected.

Appreciate any help for this.

Comment: If I understand your question, `data` will be a list of lists that you want to `zip` together? You could do `zip(*data)`

Comment: yes , this is what i was asking for. thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
to_zip = [index, field, data1, data2]
zip(*to_zip)
```

Or:

```
to_zip = [data1, data2]
zip(index, field, *to_zip)
```

Or whatever combination you need.

Comment: Is args unpacking called *splatting* also?

Comment: Don't know if that's the preferred term for Pythonistas too.

Comment: It is called so in Ruby. Here the official is unpacking itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `*data` to unpack data:

```
In [1]: zip(index,field,data1,data2)
Out[1]: 
[(0, 'name', 'john', 'david'),
 (1, 'surname', 'nash', 'davidoff'),
 (2, 'age', '88', '100'),
 (3, 'gender', 'm', 'm'),
 (4, 'location', 'konya', 'istanbul')]

In [2]: zip(index,field,*data)
Out[2]: 
[(0, 'name', 'john', 'david'),
 (1, 'surname', 'nash', 'davidoff'),
 (2, 'age', '88', '100'),
 (3, 'gender', 'm', 'm'),
 (4, 'location', 'konya', 'istanbul')]
```